# Convert unequal length columns into named list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe with columns of unequal length called 'gene_clusters' like so

```
> gene_clusters

  hi    lo    mid
  gene1 gene5 gene3
  gene2 gene8 gene9
  gene7 NA    gene10
  NA    NA    gene4
```

I've imported it from excel, so I think R has tried to compensate for the unequal lengths by filling them with NAs. Essentially, I want to create a named list like this:

```
>GeneList
## $hi
## [1] "gene1" "gene2" "gene7"  
## 
## $lo
## [1] "gene5" "gene8"  
## 
## $mid
## [1] "gene3" "gene9" "gene10" "gene4"
```

(This is just an example of my data, but in reality I have > 100 genes)

Comment: `lapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `na.omit` to drop all the `NA` values but `na.omit` returns lot of attributes which you can delete.

```
sapply(df, function(x) {x1 <- na.omit(x);attributes(x1) <- NULL;x1})

#$hi
#[1] "gene1" "gene2" "gene7"

#$lo
#[1] "gene5" "gene8"

#$mid
#[1] "gene3"  "gene9"  "gene10" "gene4"
```

---

If your column names don't have numbers as shared example you can also use `split` :

```
tmp <- na.omit(unlist(df))
split(tmp, gsub('\\d+', '', names(tmp)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `stack/split` from `base R`

```
with(na.omit(stack(df)[2:1]), split(values, ind))
#$hi
#[1] "gene1" "gene2" "gene7"

#$lo
#[1] "gene5" "gene8"

#$mid
#[1] "gene3"  "gene9"  "gene10" "gene4"
```

---

Or with `lapply`

```
lapply(df, function(x) x[complete.cases(x)])
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(hi = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene7", NA), 
lo = c("gene5", 
"gene8", NA, NA), mid = c("gene3", "gene9", "gene10", "gene4"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map

```
> map(df,~ .[!is.na(.)])
$hi
[1] "gene1" "gene2" "gene7"

$lo
[1] "gene5" "gene8"

$mid
[1] "gene3"  "gene9"  "gene10" "gene4"
```